# Trouble Implementing CoreData into a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I followed the Apple developers tutorial on implementing offline data. But I want to use CoreData. I'm struggling on opening the CoreData Context and putting it into the array, if that is even correct.

I am using Swift 3, and the latest xCode.

Here is my entity, and I don't need all the values pulled for the cell, just need to show the interesting stuff:

[image]

So this is my book.swift, which everything is based on.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit
import os.log

public class book: NSObject, NSCoding {
var title: String
var author: String
var photo: UIImage?
var isbn: String
var publisher: String

static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("books")


struct PropertyKey {
    static let title = "title"
    static let photo = "photo"
    static let author = "author"
    static let isbn = "isbn"
    static let publisher = "publisher"
}
```

And then, my BookTableViewController

```
import UIKit
import os.log
import CoreData

class BookTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//MARK: Properties
var books = [book]()
var i = 0
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? BookTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("some cell error")
    }
    // need help here, somehow grab the data from CoreData, or do I populate the book array from CoreData?


    let book = books[indexPath.row]

    cell.bookLabel.text = book.title
    cell.authorLabel.text = book.author
    cell.bookImageView.image = book.photo
    cell.publisherLabel.text = book.publisher

    return cell
}
```

All I understand is I need to somehow open a loop in the cellforrowat (at least I think) or do I need to somehow populate the array earlier on in the superviewdidload?

I've done heaps of research on CoreData, and still don't fully understand it.

Comment: where you fetch data from coredata ?

Comment: You should really be using an NSFetchedResultsController in the data source for your tableview. Give it a try, it's really quite simple.

Comment: @KKRocks I'm not sure how to fetch the data from CoreData, that's what I'm confused by.

Comment: @Abizern I tried setting that up, but had no idea what was actually going on, and how to fix it for my project.

Answer (score 2):

Your `book` class is declared as

```
public class book: NSObject, NSCoding
```

It doesn't subclass from `NSManagedObject`, so you can't use it with Core Data. All objects stored with Core Data must be instances of `NSManagedObject` or a subclass.

Later on you do this:

```
let book = books[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
```

Since `books` is an array of `book`, which does not subclass `NSManagedObject`, that's guaranteed to fail. You can't convert instances of your class to `NSManagedObject` by using `as!`. They're completely different types.

With recent versions of Xcode, subclasses of `NSManagedObject` are created automatically. Your data model shows an entity called `Book`, which means that Xcode will automatically create a class `Book` that matches the entity description. You should use that class instead of the `book` class that you've created. Use that class, and you can create, save, and fetch instances of `Book` from your managed object context.

You seem to be having difficulty with some of the most basic aspects of Core Data. I strongly recommend looking over Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/). It covers Core Data in detail including sample code. You will have difficulty with Core Data until you get the basics straight, and that guide will help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You got the code all messed up, you don't need to create some new class book which inherits NSObject, you can work with everything from NSManagedObject aka Book aka CoreDataModel entity aka I don't know what else. 
Whenever interacting with Coredata in collectionView or tableView or any component that uses some kind of dataSource protocol, you should really use NSFetchedResultsController... Anyway I find this tutorial quite useful for beginner:

https://cocoacasts.com/implement-the-nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate-protocol-with-swift-3/

Just follow the tutorial and delete the class book (You shouldn't create classes with first letter lowercased never ever... it really doesn't goes by the convention. You can store all the properties into the NSManagedObject (if you generate manually the files)